# ZF3 zend-mvc generic route for many controllers in one module not working

Tags: zend-framework-mvc, zend-framework3, zf3

I'm in ZF3, using the zend-mvc-skeleton and trying to configure a generic route that will match as many URLs as possible as I want to be able to create new controllers (including action methods of course), and have them immediately available.

The common approach described in the documentation is to write a route that matches the controller and action (same with ZF2).

Here is my `module.config.php`

```php
namespace Application;

use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'home' => [
                'type'    => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'default' => [
                'type' => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/application[/:controller[/:action]]',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                    'constraints' => [
                        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'controllers' => [/* ... */],
    'view_manager' => [/* ... */],
],
```

It works like a charm for `http://localhost/` and `http://localhost/application` calling the `indexAction()` function of the  `IndexController` class inside the `/module/Application/src/IndexController.php` file.

However, it's not working when I try to get the `fooAction()` function in the same Controller (i.e. IndexController). It's not resolving correctly `http://localhost/application/foo`. and I get the following error:

```html
A 404 error occurred

Page not found.

The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class.

Controller:
foo (resolves to invalid controller class or alias: foo)

No Exception available
```

Same error if I try `http://localhost/bar/foo` to get the `fooAction()` in the `barController`.

Do you have any idea of what's wrong with this? Any help will be appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route `http://localhost/application/foo` won't resolve to `fooAction()` in the index controller, since `/foo` in the URL will match the controller not the action. With that route setup you would need to visit `http://localhost/application/index/foo`.

To get it working you'll also need to make sure you have aliased your controller in the config, e.g. assuming you have:

```
'controllers' => [
    'invokables' => [
        'Application\Controller\Index' => \Application\Controller\IndexController::class
    ]
],
```

Then alias the controller so it matches the route parameter:

```
'controllers' => [
    'invokables' => [
        'Application\Controller\Index' => \Application\Controller\IndexController::class
    ],
    'aliases' => [
        'index' => 'Application\Controller\Index'
    ]
],
```

You'll need to add aliases that match the route parameter for each controller that isn't registered using the string you want for the route, e.g. a controller `Namespace\Controller\BarController` should be aliased to `bar`, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the errors in typo, I should have written `http://localhost/application/index/foo`as you mentionned it. The "error" came from the aliases that were missing. It's working now. Thx.

Comment: I am using this zend application inside another directory. So i was tried `http://localhost/zend/skeleton-application/public/application/index/test`. But still it saying 404. Can you ppint me where i missed?

Comment: I would guess there is a problem with the server config, assuming you're using one of the files provided with the skeleton application.  It needs to check for the file within the public directory and rewrite everything else to index.php; I think the fact that you have zf inside a subdirectory of the document root will mess with the routing in ZF3.
Better to post this as a new question.

Comment: Re-reading I'm not sure that makes sense.  What I meant was `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will be wrong and is (I assume) used for routing in ZF3. And it's best fixed (left-truncated) in the server config.

Answer (score 0):

I came here with similar problem. I have created two controllers in 
"Application" module, and two in new module "Account" with the same name.

```
Application/Controller/IndexController
Application/Controller/OverviewController
Account/Controller/IndexController
Account/Controller/OverviewController
```

here are my modules.config.php

> module/Account/config/module.config.php
>
> ```
>  return [
> 'router' => [
>     'routes' => [
>         'Account-account' => [
>          'type'  =>  Segment::class,
>          'options' =>  [
>           'route' =>  '/account[/][:controller[/][:action][/]]',
>            'defaults'  =>  [
>              '__NAMESPACE__' =>  'Account\Controller',
>              'controller'  =>  Account\Controller\IndexController::class,
>              'action'      =>  'index',
>              'locale'  =>  'en_us'
>            ],
>          ],
>          'may_terminate' =>  true,
>          'child_routes'  => [
>            'wildcard'  =>  [
>              'type'  =>  'Wildcard'
>            ],
>          ],
>        ],
>     ],
> ],
> 'controllers' => [
>     'factories' => [
>         Controller\IndexController::class     => AccountControllerFactory::class,
>         Controller\OverviewController::class  => AccountControllerFactory::class,
>     ],
>     'aliases' => [
>       'index'   =>  IndexController::class,
>       'overview'  =>  OverviewController::class
>     ]
>
> ],
> ```

and my 
    module/Application/config/module.config.php

```
return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'home' => [
                'type' => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'Application-application' => [
             'type'  =>  Segment::class,
             'options' =>  [
              'route' =>  '/application[/][:controller[/][:action][/]]',
               'defaults'  =>  [
                 '__NAMESPACE__' =>  'Application\Controller',
                 'controller'  =>  Application\Controller\IndexController::class,
                 'action'      =>  'index',
                 'locale'  =>  'en_US'
               ],
             ],
             'may_terminate' =>  true,
             'child_routes'  => [
               'wildcard'  =>  [
                 'type'  =>  'Wildcard'
               ],
             ],
           ],
        ],
    ],
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => IndexControllerFactory::class,
            Controller\OverviewController::class => IndexControllerFactory::class,
        ],
        'aliases' =>  [
          'index'     =>  IndexController::class,
         'overview'  =>  OverviewController::class,
        ]

    ],
```

With this configuration if aliases sections are commented there is a error message which says that there is invalid controller or alias (index/overview).
If there are aliases 
route: "application/overview/index" goes into Account module.

Comment: Hey were you abe to solve your problem? i have the same issue, Similar controller in different Modules with same aliases is making the problem. I can't access each module seperately. What should i do